# Show a JPopupMenu according to the location

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpopupmenu

I would like to know how to pop up a `JPopupMenu` that shows up only in a specific range, for example between (200,300) and (400, 400).

Comment: You mean, if the user clicks within the area defined by rectangle 200x300x400x400, you want a popup to show?

Comment: Yes! I have in a JPanel some rectangles and I want to pop up a menu  only in those rectangles (not everywhere) so I can show up a menu and give the option to delete it or change the size.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a `java.awt.Rectangle` of the desired size and position
- Use a `MouseListener` to determine when the `mouseClicked` and `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` event occurs, check to see if it's a [`popupTrigger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#isPopupTrigger--)
- If it is a popup trigger, use the `Rectangle` to determine if it [`containts`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains-java.awt.Point-) the [`MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint--)
- If that is all true, [`show`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show-java.awt.Component-int-int-) the popup (at the point the `MouseEvent` occured

Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details

Comment: Seriously?  What part of this doesn't provide an answer to the OPs question? At least this way the OP has a point of reference from which to actually find the solutions to their own problems and maybe learn how to search for their own answers instead of posting more open questions

Comment: Forbid we actually "try" and help people :P